# PixelBlender wrong hue. flash/actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, pixel-bender

I have a javascript which can pick colors (HSB). But in my flash element the HUE is calculated wrong.

I have this input ex: HUE: 360... SAT: 100..BRIGHTNESS: 97 but the flash element is getting a wrong color. What to do? I am using PixelBlender to change color on each pixel.

Here is my HUE.PBJ:

```
 <languageVersion : 1.0;>

 kernel HSLFilter
 <   
namespace   : "Boostworthy::Filters";
vendor      : "Ryan Taylor";
version     : 1;
description : "";
>
{
 parameter   float       hue
 < 
    minValue        :   0.0;
    maxValue        :   360.0;
    defaultValue    :   360.0;
  >;

parameter   float       saturation
<
    minValue        :   0.0;
    maxValue        :   100.0;
    defaultValue    :   0.0;
>;

parameter   float       lightness
<
    minValue        :   0.0;
    maxValue        :   100.0;
    defaultValue    :   0.0;
>;

input       image4      source;
output      pixel4      result;

void evaluatePixel()
{
    // Convert sampled pixel from RGB space to HSL space.

    pixel4 samp;
    float  sampMin;
    float  sampMax;
    float  sampDiff;
    float  sampSum;
    float  sampH;
    float  sampS;
    float  sampL;

    samp     = sampleNearest(source, outCoord());
    sampMin  = min(samp.r,  samp.g);
    sampMin  = min(sampMin, samp.b);
    sampMax  = max(samp.r,  samp.g);
    sampMax  = max(sampMax, samp.b);
    sampDiff = sampMax - sampMin;
    sampSum  = sampMax + sampMin;
    sampL    = sampSum * 0.5;

    if(sampMin == sampMax)
        sampH = 0.0;
    else if(sampMax == samp.r)
        sampH = mod(60.0 * ((samp.g - samp.b) / sampDiff), 360.0);
    else if(sampMax == samp.g)
        sampH = 60.0 * ((samp.b - samp.r) / sampDiff) + 120.0;
    else if(sampMax == samp.b)
        sampH = 60.0 * ((samp.r - samp.g) / sampDiff) + 240.0;
    else
        sampH = 0.0;

    if(sampMin == sampMax)
        sampS = 0.0;
    else if(sampL > 0.5)
        sampS = sampDiff / (2.0 - sampSum);
    else
        sampS = sampDiff / sampSum;

    // Transform the sampled HSL values by the amounts specified
    // by the hue, saturation, and lightness parameters.

    float outH;
    float outS;
    float outL;

    outH  = sampH - hue;
    outS  = sampS * (saturation / 100.0 + 1.0);
    outL  = sampL - (1.0 - (lightness / 100.0 + 1.0));

    // Convert the transformed HSL values back to RGB space.

    float q;
    float p;
    float h;

    if(outL < 0.5)
        q = outL * (1.0 + outS);
    else
        q = outL + outS - outL * outS;

    p = 2.0 * outL - q;
    h = outH / 360.0;

    float  oneOverThree = 1.0 / 3.0;
    float  twoOverThree = 2.0 / 3.0;
    float  oneOverSix   = 1.0 / 6.0;
    float3 t            = float3(h + oneOverThree, h, h - oneOverThree);

    if(t.r < 0.0)
        t.r += 1.0;
    else if(t.r > 1.0)
        t.r -= 1.0;

    if(t.g < 0.0)
        t.g += 1.0;
    else if(t.g > 1.0)
        t.g -= 1.0;

    if(t.b < 0.0)
        t.b += 1.0;
    else if(t.b > 1.0)
        t.b -= 1.0;

    pixel4 c = pixel4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, samp.a);

    if(t.r < oneOverSix)
        c.r = p + (q - p) * 6.0 * t.r;
    else if(t.r >= oneOverSix && t.r < 0.5)
        c.r = q;
    else if(t.r >= 0.5 && t.r < twoOverThree)
        c.r = p + (q - p) * 6.0 * (twoOverThree - t.r);
    else
        c.r = p;

    if(t.g < oneOverSix)
        c.g = p + (q - p) * 6.0 * t.g;
    else if(t.g >= oneOverSix && t.g < 0.5)
        c.g = q;
    else if(t.g >= 0.5 && t.g < twoOverThree)
        c.g = p + (q - p) * 6.0 * (twoOverThree - t.g);
    else
        c.g = p;

    if(t.b < oneOverSix)
        c.b = p + (q - p) * 6.0 * t.b;
    else if(t.b >= oneOverSix && t.b < 0.5)
        c.b = q;
    else if(t.b >= 0.5 && t.b < twoOverThree)
        c.b = p + (q - p) * 6.0 * (twoOverThree - t.b);
    else
        c.b = p;

    // Apply the final ARGB color to the pixel.

    result = c;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the original shader version used -180 to 180 hue parameter, you most likely have your t.b below -1 for certain hues, which is unaccounted for in this shader. Change it for -180 to 180 with default value being 0, and watch the fun.